copy files in gforth from filenames given on CLI
I Would copy fileA to fileB from cli just like
gforth script.fs -- fileA fileB

the '--' seems to be mandatory to void gforth trying to load it as additionnal forth code
official documentation example says
0 Value fd-in
0 Value fd-out
: open-input ( addr u -- )  r/o open-file throw to fd-in ;
: open-output ( addr u -- )  w/o create-file throw to fd-out ;

s" foo.in" open-input
s" foo.out" open-output

: copy-file ( -- )
  begin
      line-buffer max-line fd-in read-line throw
  while
      line-buffer swap fd-out write-line throw
  repeat ;


but I would get filenames from CLI

so I tryied many things around 

\ Define buffer size for filenames and IO operations
256 Constant filename-len
4096 Constant io-buffer-len

\ Allocate buffers for filenames
Create source-filename filename-len allot
Create dest-filename filename-len allot
Create io-buffer io-buffer-len allot

\ Variables to store file IDs
Variable source-file-id
Variable dest-file-id

\ Define a word to calculate the length of a string up to a maximum length
: str-len ( c-addr max-len -- n )
  0 swap  ( n c-addr )
  begin  dup 1+  ( n c-addr+1 )
         over + c@  ( n c-addr+1 c-addr+1[i] )
         while  1+  ( n+1 )
  repeat  drop ;

\ Safely store command-line arguments into buffers
: safe-store ( addr len arg# -- )
  arg swap  ( c-addr u arg# )
  2dup >r str-len r> min  ( c-addr u n )
  move ;

: store-filenames
  \ Store first filename, ensure it doesn't exceed buffer size
  source-filename filename-len 1 safe-store
  \ Store second filename, ensure it doesn't exceed buffer size
  dest-filename filename-len 2 safe-store ;

\ Open the source file for reading
: open-source-file
  source-filename filename-len s" r" open-file throw source-file-id ! ;

\ Open the destination file for writing (create if not exists)
: open-dest-file
  dest-filename filename-len s" w" open-file throw dest-file-id ! ;

\ Copy content from the source file to the destination file
: copy-file
  begin
    source-file-id @ io-buffer io-buffer-len read-file throw
  while
    io-buffer swap dest-file-id @ write-file throw
  repeat ;

\ Close the files
: close-files
  source-file-id @ close-file throw
  dest-file-id @ close-file throw ;

\ Main routine
: main
  store-filenames
  open-source-file
  open-dest-file
  copy-file
  close-files ;

\ Execute the main routine
main

a previous version was
4194304 Constant max-line
256 constant filename-size
Create line-buffer max-line 2 + allot
create filename-input filename-size allot
create filename-ouput filename-size allot
\ filename 
variable input-file-id
variable output-file-id
\ close files buffers
: cleaning
    input-file-id close-file throw 
    output-file-id close-file throw 
    cr 0 (bye)
;
\ create buffers for data treatment
: initiating
    filename-input count r/o open-file throw input-file-id !
    filename-ouput w/o create-file throw output-file-id !
;
\ read filenames from cli arguments
: getparemters
    1 arg filename-input swap move
    2 arg filename-ouput swap move
; 
\ copy file 
: copying
    begin
        line-buffer max-line input-file-id read-line throw
    while
        line-buffer swap output-file-id write-line throw
    repeat
;
\ main code
: main
    getparemters
    initiating
    copying
    cleaning
;
main 

but I alwoys fail to manage the filename capture creating memory errors or different kind of errors
I'm lost about it

Finally found how to fix it
naw code is
65535 constant maxline
\ buffer
create linebuffer maxline 2 + allot
\ filenames
2variable   filenameinput
2variable   filenameouput
\ file ids
0 value     inputfileid
0 value     outputfileid
\ close files buffers
: COLORIZE 27 EMIT ." [" base @ >R 0 <# #S #> type R> base ! ." m"  ; \ ASCII TERMINAL ONLY 
: cleaning
    inputfileid close-file throw 
    outputfileid close-file throw 
    0 (bye)
;
\ create buffers for data treatment
: initiating
    filenameinput 2@ r/o open-file throw to inputfileid 
    filenameouput 2@ r/w create-file throw to outputfileid
;
\ read filenames from cli arguments
: getparemters
    argc @ 3 <> if 
        \ manage bad parameter number
        cr cr 91 colorize   
        0 arg type ."  thisprogram.fs filename destinationfilename"
        0 colorize cr cr cr 
        1 (bye)
    else
        \ get filenames
        1 arg filenameinput 2!
        2 arg filenameouput 2!
    then
; 
\ copy file 
: copying
    begin
        \ line buffer read
        linebuffer maxline inputfileid read-line throw
    while
        \ line buffer copy
        linebuffer swap outputfileid write-line throw
    repeat
;
\ main code
: main
    getparemters
    initiating
    copying
    cleaning
;
main 

this would work fine for any ascii files
